# Bounded functions composed with Möbius maps

Tags: complex-analysis

Hopefully easy question here:

What is the most succinct method/technique to prove the following statement?:

> Let $u \in L^{\infty}(\Bbb D)$. Show that
>   $||u(\varphi_{z})||_{\infty}$ is independent of $z$ for $z \in \Bbb D$,
>   where $\varphi_{z}$ is the Möbius automorphism on the unit disc
>   $\Bbb D$ in the complex plane.

It seems like an obvious statement due to the fact that $\varphi_{z}$ is an automorphism, but what is the fastest way to write it up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\|u \circ \phi_z\| = \sup_{\zeta \in \mathbb{D}} |u(\phi_z(\zeta))| = \sup_{\zeta\in\mathbb{D}} \{ |u(w)| : w=\phi_z(\zeta) \} = \sup_{w\in \mathbb{D}} |u(w)| = \| u \|
$$
where the third equality uses that $\phi_z(\mathbb{D}) = \mathbb{D}$.